# Is there a version of L'Hopital Theorem in Measure Theory?

Tags: measure-theory

I was checking the proof of the theorem (or one of the proofs) and the Mean Value Theorem is used which immediately says this proof cannot be modified (a priori) for a Measure version, however, is there any version of the theorem in terms of measurable functions (involved in a quotient) both of them allowing derivatives almost everywhere?

Comment: I suppose that with "in measure theory" you really mean something like "for absolutely continuous/weakly differentiable functions", don't you?